# Lack of jquery ajax success setting

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple checkbox that is either checked on or off by querying the database. A user can change this value and I send a request via `ajax`. The url is wacky because it is a Joomla component (not important for this question, but just in case).

```
$(function() {

$("#iButton").iButton();

$('#iButton').change(function() {
    var checkedLength = $(this + ':checked').length;
    if(1 == checkedLength){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=globaldetection&id_hash=<?php echo $id_hash; ?>&global_monitoring='+checkedLength+'&format=raw'
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=globaldetection&id_hash=<?php echo $id_hash; ?>&global_monitoring='+checkedLength+'&format=raw'
        });
    }
});

});

<?php
//highlight whether the checkbox is on or off
if ($userstatus == "ENABLED") //get this value from server
{
    //turned on
    $global_monitoring = "checked=\"checked\"";
}
else
{
    $global_monitoring = "";
}

?>
    <div class="dropshadow">
    <p id="iButtontext">
      <input type="checkbox" id="iButton" <?php echo $global_monitoring; ?> name="iButton_checkbox" />
    </p>
    </div>
```

This works fine and as I expect but I have several questions here:

1. I duplicate the `ajax` function twice depending on the condition. Is there a better way to do this or completely acceptable?
2. I'm only passing in url and no other settings. I've always used the `success` setting but in this case there is no other response I need to do. I know it is optional but should I be doing something else at that point?
3. Any other settings I should be passing into ajax? It just seems too...simple.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Both ajax requests are **IDENTICAL**. Why do you have 2 then?

Comment: They are not identical, `checkedLength` is either 1 or 0. So I could put an if statement around the url instead of duplicating the entire `ajax` call. Although I'm not sure that's possible. Either way, that's the point of question #1, there must be a better way.

Comment: @zerkms has a point, remove the if. The use of the variable `checkedLength` makes the if redundant. Also, does the PHP in the query string do what you intend it to do?

Comment: @GerardSexton Ok, got it. Yes the PHP query string does the trick. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Tom Thats good. Just checking.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment to incorporate it in my answer, but the way you had that selector I don't see how it could possibly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the if/else structure at all, because in both branches you have an identical line of code so if you just put that line of code on its own it would work (it would still use the value of `checkedLength`).

However, `$(this + ':checked').length` doesn't make sense - your selector concatenates the *string* `':checked'` to the end of the *object* `this`. I don't see how that could be working at the moment. An equivalent way to get the result as a "length" would be `$(this).filter(':checked').length`, which is kind of clunky. Or you can test it as a boolean with `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`, except even that is way more complicated than it needs to be when `this.checked` does the same job.

Given that you can get the checked state directly with `this.checked` I think the following is simpler (and definitely more efficient):

```
$('#iButton').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=globaldetection&id_hash=<?php echo $id_hash; ?>&global_monitoring='
            + (this.checked ? 1 : 0) + '&format=raw'
    });
});
```

(I'm assuming the `.length` you were originally using could only ever be `0` or `1` since the event is on an element that you select by id.)

> *"I'm only passing in url and no other settings. I've always used the success setting but in this case there is no other response I need to do. I know it is optional but should I be doing something else at that point?"*

No. If you don't need to do anything on success then don't specify a success callback - it may be wise to specify an error callback though, in case the call doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks. But for some reason it doesn't work. If I use `var checkLength = $(this).filter(':checked').length;` and the single ajax call it does. Any idea?

Comment: The only idea I have as to why it wouldn't work is if the `iButton()` plugin that you seem to be using causes a problem with checking the DOM properties directly. Using `(this.checked ? 1 : 0)` works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/y24zY/, so there should be no problem substituting that for `$(this).filter(':checked').length`. Anyway, if you change nothing else in your original code it would still be a big improvement to remove the if/else and just have the `$.ajax()` line on its own.